# How to disable vpn connection when app is terminated in iOS?

Tags: ios, vpn

I'm implementing Personal VPN by PacketTunnel. Through startVPNTunnel method of NETunnelProviderManager, i checked whether VPN Connection is run well.

However, I have a problem. I added the exit code of vpn connection in applicationWillTerminate to disable vpn connection when app is terminated like following code below. But it doesn't work.

If test this code, loadAllFromPreferences is run but callback function of loadAllFromPreferences isn't called. This code runs well anywhere except applicationWillTerminate. Why it doesn't work? Is there any way to disable vpn when app is terminated?

```
func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        NETunnelProviderManager.loadAllFromPreferences { (managers, error) in
            var manager:NETunnelProviderManager?=nil;
            for m in managers! {
                if m != nil {
                    if m.localizedDescription == "profile" {
                        manager = m;
                        break
                    }
                }
            }
            manager?.connection.stopVPNTunnel()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623111-applicationwillterminate) of `applicationWillTerminate(application:)`:

> Your implementation of this method has approximately five seconds to perform any tasks and return. If the method does not return before time expires, the system may kill the process altogether.

If `applicationWillTerminate` is called but the closure is not make sure that it does not take more than "approximately" (sic) 5 seconds.

I have not used the libraries you are using but from a general point of view there are probably better strategies than iterating over all available managers. Like storing a reference/identifier to a given manager when starting a connection and using that reference/identifier to terminate it.

Comment: I have solved by storing manager instance. Thank you!